# Spring 4 Rest with Hibernate Validator does not display inline message

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I have a sample Spring Rest service project in which I am trying to implement hibernate validator. I am stuck right now in displaying the error message to the rest caller. I have the code for Spring Rest , DTO listed below

Controller

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.project.home.rest.SampleDTO;

@RestController(value = "/validator")
public class ValidatorController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validate(@Valid @RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDTO) {

        return "Hello User Validator Serivce in play";

    }
}
```

SampleDTO

```
public class SampleDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 18, message = "ID must be greater than 18 characters long")
    @Max(value = 100, message = "ID must be less than 100 Characters Long")
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Name is Compulsory")
    private String name;

    @Email(message = "Email address not Valid")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email address can not be null")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

When accessing the Rest Service via Rest Client I do see the 400 bad request error but the error messages are not dislpayed.
The error I get in Tomcat console is

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.matitech.it.advice.CentralControllerHandler.handleMethodArgumentException(java.lang.String)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [0] [type=java.lang.String]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.matitech.it.advice.CentralControllerHandler]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.matitech.it.advice.CentralControllerHandler.handleMethodArgumentException(java.lang.String)]

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have also tried the alternate version with BindingResult but in that case I get 500 Internal server error
Modified code

```
Controller
@RestController(value = "/validator")
public class ValidatorController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validate(@Valid @RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException();
        }
        return "Hello User Validator Serivce in play";

    }
}

public class MethodArgumentNotValidException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7764697079393527116L;

    public MethodArgumentNotValidException() {
        super();
    }

    public MethodArgumentNotValidException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice

    public class CentralControllerHandler {


        @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
        public ResponseEntity<String> handleMethodArgumentException(String message){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(message,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RequestMapping` should throw a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` if the validation fails.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity validate(@Valid @RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDTO) {
    //this should throw a MethodArgumentNotValidException if the validation fails
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Validation successful", HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Create an exception handler like this and return the validation messages to the caller.

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
     return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getBindingResult(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}
```

Comment: I did that earlier but then I get the Rest Response back as Internal server error 500 and not bad request, I have pasted that code in the Modified Code Section

Comment: If you get status 500 this means that your CentralControllerHandler is not working. In your code snippet I do not see the @ControllerAdvice annotation above the CentralControllerHandler. Try that.

Comment: I do have that annotation , it did not get include in the code formatting

Comment: Start debugging. Does the code in your @ExceptionHandler excecute?

Comment: In the modified code the CentralControllerhandler is never called , the code goes into MethodArgumentNotValidExceeption and from there throws exception

Comment: I see it now, in the parameters of your @ExceptionHandler method you except a String as parameter, the method needs the thrown exception as parameter like so: (MethodArgumentNotValidException e). By the way the GlobalControllerHandler works, as seen in the stacktrace you posted.

Comment: Yes that did the trick for me also I changed my CentralControllerHandlerAdvice to llok more like this http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/